# how can c# help in drawing using memory layers concept?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, memory, drawing

i am facing problem in drawing dynamically in a picture box. i works very good when the drawing objects are few but as the drawing objects increases the response time of my GUI is getting worse and worse, my GUI works very well up to 90 drawing objects but i have to support more than 1000 so this technique didn't work for me.

know i have decided to adopt layers mechanism, i mean i will draw different layers of drawing in memory and then XOR them to load the final image to my display.

the question is "i Can play directly with memory do draw layers using C# (Examples needed?)"

other ideas are also appreciated,

(Drawing objects means the shapes line,circles etc. that i have to draw on my GUI)

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I do any custom drawing, I make sure that I draw onto a bitmap and then just display the bitmap.  You don't want to have to constantly redraw an image if it hasn't changed.

Comment: as i told before i have a dynamic image not a static one i am currently using the same as you told but i need some more efficient method like memory layers.